How to get a label value from another metric and add it on prometheus
Suppose a metric is like the following,
weblogic_id(domain="name", instance="instance"}
Is there any way I can get the domain="name" from that metric and add it to all other metrics that started with weblgic_?
for example,
if a metric is like this
weblogic_server_listen_port{instance="instance",name="name"}
then it will be
weblogic_server_listen_port{domain="name", instance="instance",name="name"}
Thanks
